# Using for instead of .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, each

My assumptions are the .each() function is slower than a for loop when dealing with a lot of elements.

My problem is with the for loop i'm unable to manipulate the elements as i'm looping through them. I can do this fine with .each(). This could be a simple answer.

Javascript:

```
var element = $('#element h3');
var length = element.length;
var newHtml;

for(i=0;i<length;i++){

  newHtml = element[i].html();

  ...test newHtml
}
```

The code breaks when I try to grab the .html() of the element. I've seen posts that explain this is the way to loop through elements with a for loop, but grabbing information from them and manipulating them was never addressed.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you really doing this just because it executes faster? This is premature optimization. Just use `.each`, the bottleneck is going to be `.html()` anyway, not the loop.

Comment: `element` is a misleading name; it should be plural.

Comment: @SLaks is right it shud be `elements`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`element[i]` is a raw DOM element, not a jQuery object.  (just like `this` in `.each()`)

You want `element.eq(i)`, which will return a jQuery object wrapping the `i`<sup>th</sup> element.

Comment: Or `element[i].innerHTML` which supposedly has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an over optimized solution to handle huge amounts of `h3` in a single stretch, forget `jquery`.

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
var headings = element.getElementsByTagName('h3');
var length = headings.length;
var newHtml;

for(i=0;i<length;i++){

  newHtml = headings[i].innerHTML;

  ...test newHtml
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing jQuery with javascript like in `element[i].html();` 
your code should be like this

```
function myfunction(){
    var element = document.getElementsByName('element');
    var length = element.length;
    var newHtml;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        newHtml = element[i].innerHTML;
    }
}
```

note that document.getElementById() only return one result so you have to put "element" in name attr. and frankly .each is way easier